# GRPC with one server and several clients

Tags: python, c++, grpc

Q1:
When I have a GRPC connection with one server(`S`) and several clients(`C1` and `C2`)(Using Response-streaming RPC).
I wonder how frames `S` sends to `C1` and `C2`?
For example, there's 10 frames that server needs to response. What will `C1` and `C2` receive separately and Why?

1. `C1` gets 5 frames and `C2` gets another 5(I tried my program and seems it acts like this way)
2. `C1` gets all 10 frames `C2` gets the same all 10 copies.

And is there a way to choose from 1 or 2?

Q2:
a GRPC connection with only one server(`S`) and only one client(`C`) this time(Using Response-streaming RPC still).
I forcely stop `C`(i.e. `ctrl+c`) and restart the program(`C_second`).But this time `C_second` still only gets parts of frames that `S` sends.
Seems the connection between `S` and `C`(forcely stopped) still be alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. gRPC is point-to-point. The connection `C1 -> S` and `C2 -> S` are separate. Any message that `S` sends will be directed at either `C1` or `C2`. If duplication is required between clients, the server application logic will need to manage this itself.
2. Great question. This is a point that people often miss in designing their protocol. gRPC itself is *stateless*. If a channel dies, the client will not attempt to download previously sent messages. Instead, the RPC needs to be made idempotent *or* stateful. That is, if checkpointing needs to happen in a streaming API, the application needs to manage that itself.